# How to serialize database first EF5 object to Byte array?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

How am I best to serialize an Entity Framework object to a byte array (so I can cache it in redis)?

Serialization normally requires attributes adding to properties, but because this project is DB first, I can't add the attributes due to code generation (and also I'm not sure how I'd say what I want serializing without .NET trying to serialize the entire database because of going through nested collections).

What I would *like* to achieve is something like:

```
Product product;
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
product = new ProductRepository(context).GetItem(123456);
}

byte[] productSerialized = Serialize(product);
```

where whatever has been loaded by the repo is serialized, and whatever isn't is ignored. If I can even get close to this, that would be great.

Comment: Your classes will be generated as `partial` to get around these kind of issues. Just add the attribute in another file.

Comment: Another option is to not serialize the EF objects, but have DTO objects which are easily converted back and forth - http://entitiestodtos.codeplex.com/

Comment: @BenRobinson I didn't know partials could do that. The amount of nested collections might still be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Product` is a struct, then this might help you:

```
    public byte[] Serialize(Product p)
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Product));
        // Both managed and unmanaged buffers required.
        var bytes = new byte[size];
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        // Copy object byte-to-byte to unmanaged memory.
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(p, ptr, false);
        // Copy data from unmanaged memory to managed buffer.
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        // Release unmanaged memory.
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: It does not work for classes. But of your class is very complex, how about adding a `Serialize()` member to `Product` that converts all your properties/fields into byte arrays and join them to one big `byte[]` (using `BitConverter`)? Or is your code so dynamic that this cannot be done?

Comment: Because everything is so integrated, I don't think this could be done. By the sounds of it, I'm going to need a "CachableProduct" class, and do some transforming

Answer (score -1):

You can use a MemoryStream and get its buffer, like this:

```
    public byte[] Serialize(Product product)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product)); 
        serializer.Serialize(stream, product);
        return stream.GetBuffer();
    }
```

Comment: The problem I have (I mentioned this in the post) is that due to code generation, I can't add the [Serializable] attribute. When I update the database, all the class files are re-generated.

Comment: In that cause you can use the XmlSerializer. That one does not require your Product class to have an attribute. Answer will be edited (sorry; I did not read it correctly).

Comment: Got further with that, but it's trying to serialiaze every attribute - loaded or not. Plus some of the attributes go to an interface, which fails the serialization.

Comment: XmlSerializer serializes every public property. Maybe make these properties private; not sure how it will work out. It is also possible to suppress the serialization of individual public properties by an attribute, but you already said that this is not possible.